# Test controller method that uses request-url with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I wrote a gem for Rails that extends `ApplicationController` with a certain method. This method parses the current URL and uses the result to do a lookup. It looks something like this (simplified):

```
@current_account = Account.where(subdomain => request.subdomains.first).first
```

I want to include a test in the gem that asserts that the subdomain is looked up correctly based on a given URL.

I am running into two problems trying to write the test:

1) Since i'm testing within a gem, there is no controller (or Rails app for that matter) so I don't actually know where to start (Unit test, Controller test?)

2) I have searched everywhere, but I cannot find a way to setup the `request` hash in Rspec for testing. I would expect I would be able to do something like `request.url = 'account1.example.com'`

Any help on how to setup a proper test for this situation on Rspec is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a controller test, then the URLs are usually specified on the configuration, like:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'www.test.host' }
```

that is, if you're testing this as a rails application.

To test that a method in an abstract class works, your best option is to create a Test Subclass, and test using that. Something like

```
class TestController < ApplicationController; end
```

and then do your specs around this controller, which should behave exactly as an `ApplicationController`

*EDIT*

This would be an example of what I am proposing:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: 'fake page' #This is so the action does not fail
  end

end

describe TestController do
  it 'searches for the current account in the right subdomain' do
    Account.should_receive(:where).with({subdomain: 'www'})

    get :index
  end
end
```

Comment: That does sound sensible although I still don't have a clear picture what the test would look like. Could you show me an example of the test using your approach?